# What is the maximum process Id on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, pid

What is the maximum process id I can get by calling `DWORD GetProcessId(HANDLE)` or `DWORD  GetCurrentProcessId()`? It is not documented on the API's documentation page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Processes and Threads](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/ba-p/723824) blog post by Mark Russinovich number of processes is limited only by available memory. So theoretically maximum process id is [DWORD_MAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4,294,967,295) aligned to 4: 0xFFFFFFFC (as pid/tid values are aligned to 4 on Windows).

Comment: But where did you get the notion that a PID is a DWORD? “PIDs are divisible on 4” is confusing and vague. If you mean that they are divisible *by* four, then your assumption that they are DWORDs is baseless because any number is divisible by four. If you mean they are DWORD *aligned* in memory, then again, it is a specious assumption because even a char can be DWORD-aligned.

Comment: I wanted to say that you need to align DWORD_MAX (0xFFFFFFFF) to 4. So the maximum PID is 0xFFFFFFFC.

Comment: But where did your get DWORD from? The word “DWORD” is not present anywhere in the article you linked to. Is there a doc somewhere that says PIDs are DWORDs?

Comment: You can look at GetProcessId function. It returns PID as DWORD.

Comment: Like [I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868218/17868538?noredirect=1#comment29969056_17868515), that doesn’t mean it actually *uses* the whole range of a DWORD. For example, some API return an `int` or a `DWORD`, but have a smaller range of *valid* values such as `0` and `1` (or `0` and `non-zero`). They round the type up something that can hold the valid range, even if that means there’s too much space that is left unused.

Comment: Just a note that you shouldn't rely on PIDs being [divisible by four](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/02/28/7925962.aspx). It's purely coincidence.

Comment: should have given an actual value instead of "near DWORD_MAX or anything". What if someone answers others by:" the meaning of this word? please go to dictionary p.342"

Comment: @Near I added more details to the answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find an official statement on it but since it's stored and returned as a DWORD you should assume it can use the entire 32-bit range. In practical systems I've never seen a PID large than ~200,000 though - since Windows will reuse PIDs they rarely get larger.

Comment: I've seen PIDs in the 4 billion range. But I've been around a while.

Comment: @RaymondChen :) Thanks for that, new one on me.

Comment: I believe Win9x used pointers into the kernel as PIDs, so they were generally high in the range of DWORDs.

Comment: Just because PID related functions return a DWORD does not necessarily mean that they are DWORDs; many functions return a type larger than the maximum actual value. I’m not sure why, but I’ve always had the idea that PIDs were 16-bit. A quick search will find that at least *nix systems (even 64-bit ones) apparently do limit PIDs to 32,768, however I have seen some people mention PIDs in Windows over 100,000, so I’m not sure and am searching for some definitive information.

Comment: I've seen much larger process Id's (in the 10's of millions) on systems with applications that have handle leaks, and the process Id's are not made available for re-use.