# What is the maximum size of SYSJOBID?

Tags: sas

I'm capturing the automatic `sysjobid` macro variable in a table, and so it would help to know the range of possible types (Character/Numeric) and values (which are operating system dependent).

**EDIT:**  whilst theoretically any value could be passed, what is most useful is to know what is the maximum in 99% of cases.

What is the largest value that any of you have witnessed in your deployments?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: I'd like the answer to cover all relevant operating systems - it's part of a public macro library

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

- Linux:  32768 for 32-bit systems, or 4194304 for 64-bit systems ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-process-id))
- Windows: up to `DWORD_MAX` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868218/what-is-the-maximum-process-id-on-windows)), which I think in this context is 4294967295 ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/296az74e.aspx))

Can anyone fill in the blanks for some of the other operating systems supported by SAS? There are many...

Comment: ok you raise a valid point, the value COULD be a very large string (the maximum for which is 32,767 in SAS).   I'll rephrase the question slightly so that it is more useful

Comment: The numbers quoted above are maximum values, not maximum lengths. The sas character variable length limit is not applicable here.

Comment: aah ok - so you're saying that the value returned is always numeric?  and an integer?

Comment: As a macro variable, `&SYSJOBID` is always text - it's up to you to input the value appropriately if you want to store it as a numeric variable in a data set. I am not aware of any operating systems that have process IDs other than non-negative base-10 integers, but it's conceivable that one exists.

Comment: that's what I thought, hence the question - I'd like to store it appropriately :-)